# Inject Spring defined propery into controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to inject property with value inside my controller by using Spring Framework servlet.xml config file. My controller starts like this

```
package lv.lu.meetings.portal.mvc.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import lv.lu.meetings.domain.jpa.User;
import lv.lu.meetings.domain.jpa.meeting.Attendance;
import lv.lu.meetings.domain.jpa.meeting.Invite;
import lv.lu.meetings.domain.jpa.meeting.InviteStatus;
import lv.lu.meetings.domain.jpa.meeting.Meeting;
import lv.lu.meetings.domain.jpa.notification.Notification;
import lv.lu.meetings.domain.redis.Friend;
import lv.lu.meetings.interfaces.service.NotificationService;
import lv.lu.meetings.interfaces.service.UserService;
import lv.lu.meetings.portal.mvc.WebConst;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

/**
 * Controller for displaying application home page.
 * 
 * Supports multiple tab views: Main, Friends, Notifications, Meetings. 
 */


@Controller
public class HomePageController {

    // limit meeting count
    // defined in meetings-servlet.xml
    private String limit;
    public String getLimit() {
        return limit;
    }

    public void setLimit(String limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }
```

My meetings-servlet.xml file is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Spring Web application configuration file -->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <!-- Support for component autowiring -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="lv.lu.meetings"/>

    <!-- URL mapping for annotation-based Spring Web MVC controllers -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="loginInterceptor"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Limit output data -->
    <bean id="HomePageController" class="lv.lu.meetings.portal.mvc.controller.HomePageController">
        <property name="limit" value="10" />
    </bean>
```

I'm getting error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMapping' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/meetings-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler 'HomePageController' to URL path [/home]: There is already handler of type [class lv.lu.meetings.portal.mvc.controller.HomePageController] mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
```

It's definitely smth easy to configure, but i am new to Java and Spring Framework itself, so help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are currently creating 2 `HomePageController` beans. One from

```
<!-- Limit output data -->
<bean id="HomePageController" class="lv.lu.meetings.portal.mvc.controller.HomePageController">
    <property name="limit" value="10" />
</bean>
```

and the other from

```
<context:component-scan base-package="lv.lu.meetings"/>
```

and the `@Controller` annotation on

```
@Controller
public class HomePageController {
```

Assuming you have a `@RequestMapping` handler method in this class, Spring will try to register it twice and fail since you can't have two handlers for the same URL.

Choose one or the other bean. If you want to go the annotation way, you can inject the value directly

```
@Value("10")
private String limit;
```

or use a [property placeholder](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/).

Comment: Right, i also have  @RequestMapping(value = "/home/meetings", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayMeetings(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) { mapping where i want to use my defined property. How can i choose only one ? I can't remove <context:component-scan base-package="lv.lu.meetings"/>

Comment: @Slammer Then get rid of the `<bean>` declaration for `HomePageController` and find another way to set the limit. One is the way I described.

Comment: Yes, but with provided property placeholder example's syntax it seems that it is valid for jstl only

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property with the `@Value` annotation reading a value from a property file (or whatever):

```
@Value("${my.limit}")
private String limit;
```

You can also exclude the `HomePageController` from the component scanning:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="lv.lu.meetings">
  <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="HomePageController$"/>
</context:component-scan>
```